# Get the ID of an element using Selenium Web Driver in PHP

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am building an application in PHP/MySQL/jQuery and it displays a list of items to the user, with a blank field at the bottom to add a new item. There's an Ajax blur event that saves your data to the database, then replaces the "new" row with a regular row, which includes the text you entered and an edit button. If you click the edit button, you it turns the text back into an input. All of these have IDs like item_n and edit_n where n is the ID in the database. What I'm really after is n.

Using Selenium (I've been focusing on Web Driver, but I'm open to using IDE), I'd like to create a new item, then click the edit button and alter it, but I don't know the ID of the edit button.

I've been able to create tests where I create a new row, then confirm that it's there using assertTextPresent, but I can't find a way to get the ID of the new row (which will be item_n).

I've tried using :contains, but it always returns an empty string. I've tried a few CSS and Xpath selectors, ranging from general to specific:

```
$elem = $this->_session->element('css', 'div.item_row div.item_title:contains("'.$new_item.'")');
$elem = $this->_session->element('xpath', '//div:contains("'.$new_task.'")');
```

I also tried just getting the second to last element in the list (since the last is the new-row field), but I'd really prefer to not have to rely on sorting.

The question below indicates Selenium RC could call JavaScript:
[Selenium RC: How to check if an element has a given attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959188/selenium-rc-how-to-check-if-an-element-has-a-given-attribute)

I know Web Driver succeeded Selenium RC, but I'm not sure if Web Driver supports RC commands such as the above. That said, I gave it a try anyway. The JavaScript function I wrote to get the ID returns null. I did test the function outside of Selenium, so I know it's working.

I'm using the Facebook PHP Web Driver implementation, but I'm not married to it:
https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Create an IWebElement instance of the element. Then get the id attribute of the IWebElement. Below is the C# code for the same:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPAth("//XpathOfTheElement"));
string id = element.GetAttribute("id")
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I believe the element function I am using is the the same as the findElement function you mention. I can't find good documentation for the PHP bindings, and the functions seem to differ rather dramatically from those of other languages. For example WebDriver::findElement returns "findElement is not a valid webdriver command."